# How can I use kernel discriminant analysis?

Tags: matlab, signals

I am going to use kernel discriminant analysis in MATLAB. I found out that this performs better than PCA or LDA. However, MATLAB has no function for this. So, is there anyone who know this algorithm for using feature extraction purpose?
Is there any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Plenty of links on Google for "kernel discriminant analysis matlab", like [this one](http://asi.insa-rouen.fr/enseignants/~arakotom/toolbox/index.html)

Comment: Performs better than PCA or LDA for what purpose? PCA and LDA do a pretty damn good job in some situations, especially with computational constraints.